# When writing a question "Similar questions" block overlaps bottom of the site

Tags: bug

When cursor is in input field (textarea in html) for the question's text, the "Similar questions" block overlaps the bottom of the site. I think it should stay limited to the grey block (either `<div id="content">` or `<div id="mainbar" class="ask-mainbar">` in html).

There is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It's probably happening on other sites too.